# Docker stuck on "Waiting for SSH to be available..."

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

I'm using a docker with Windows and Hyper-v to create containers. I've added a docker machine **vmachine** to my docker configuration. First time the machine is created, it gets an IP (although I cannot manage nginx to access it - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) and finishes the bootup.

When I turn off the machine and then try to boot it, i get stuck in this message

**Waiting for SSH to be available...**

And it doesn't evolve from there. The machine is booted, however, I get an IPv6 when I input the command `docker-machine ip vmachine` like - `fe80::215:5dff:fe21:10b` insted of a IPv4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you expecting an IPv4 address specifically? Can you not use the IPv6 address?

Comment: Although I find it easier to use IPv4, that's not the issue, but a consequence... The issue is that it stucks in **Waiting for SSH to be available...**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem here is by default docker uses `DockerNAT` network switch. You should create a new external network switch instead. This issue is covered [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-docker-for-windows-docker-machine-create/8032/4) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/). You can create an external network switch using the below command

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch external-switch tempbox1
```

or you can create one through the UI

[image: external network switch]

Be sure to **reboot** the device after creating the external switch.

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows 10 and `docker-machine.exe version 0.8.2, build e18a919`. On the Hyper-V Manager UI I created that external virtual switch, then I rebooted the PC, then on a PowerShell with administrative priviledges I typed `PS C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch VirtualSwitch4DockerMachine fooVM`. I think there may be some issues with permissions on `C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>>.ssh/id_rsa` (on cygwin `ls -la` gives for `id_rsa`: `Administrators   Domain Users`), but I don't see any other attempt I could perform.

Comment: This worked for me.  Using an External Virtual Switch did the trick.

Comment: This happened to me after a Windows 10 feature upgrade. Suddenly, my hyper-v VMs used by docker-machine were in the weeds. I had to end up deleting my existing virtual (external) switch, and recreate it, and reattach it to the VMs.

Comment: After enabling an external switch I have no access to the internet

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and non of the solutions worked. Turns out that according to [this answer](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/666#issuecomment-294592183), docker launches SSH with Unix specific elements. This is said to have been fixed in the releases that followed, but I still encountered the 'Waiting for SSH' issue. I resolved this by simply using GIT bash to run all docker related SSH commands.

Comment: it works for me.  using gitbash won't stuck on the step `“Waiting for SSH to be available…”`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's solved it for me.

Turns out Windows 10 starting version 1709 has a built in SSH client at C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH. [Here](https://poweruser.blog/enabling-the-hidden-openssh-server-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-1709-and-why-its-great-51c9d06db8df)'s an article discussing it.

Looks like docker is using that SSH implementation and it's not compatible. I didn't look for a proper way to remove the built-in SSH implementatino in Windows 10, and simply renamed the folder. That was enough to fix it for me.

Comment: It works for me.  For me, I run docker-machine.exe in wsl2.

Answer (score 2):

Use the switch `--native-ssh`

for example `docker-machine --native-ssh ....` Get more details from [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/)

Answer (score 1):

docker-machine.exe -debug create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "External Virtual Switch" --hyperv-cpu-count "1" --hyperv-memory "1024" --hyperv-disk-size "20000" mydockervm

make sure to have additional VirtualSwitch configure , with external network driver selected ,  Uninstall virtualbox

Use the debug switch to see the exact error , for me it was not able to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

After doing what is mentioned in the above suggestions and if you are running docker on a windows machine try to login using cli. This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Command Promt Docker will stuck at Waiting for SSH to be available..., So change to use GIT BASH as @Dave Howson said it will work.

Comment: This should a comment @Gary

Answer (score 0):

If you're using oracle VM you must ensure first that your new cloud vm is `running`.

**Before**:
[image]

**After**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10 and Docker Desktop. I did the following steps which helped solve the problem:

1. docker-compose down --remove-orphans
2. docker system prune -f
3. Stop Docker Desktopk, kill in the Windows task manager all running docker services
4. Restart Docker desktop

And everything worked well.